# Laavan -Growth curve models with indirect effects

Tags: r, structural-equation-modeling, mediation, lavaan, growth-model

I have a latent growth model (growth curve model) with time-varying covariates.
I also want to to test for the possibility of indirect effects through the tine varying covariate.
Does Laavan allow for such a model and if so, what will be the code?
Thanks
Shira [image]

Comment: Please tell us more about your experimental/study design, and your data

Comment: Im testing the effects of political activity on social media during election campaign using panel data I have 6 waves of data collection IV-political information received.
M- political expression on social media
DV - attitudes

Comment: Yes, you can code that model.